# Updating values of a large core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using core data to create about 1800 records. I really dont have a problem with inserting values to core data but when i try to update the existing values it takes ages. This is how i am doing it:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Sales"];
        NSArray *Sales=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        for (int i = 0; i<Sales.count; i++)
        {
            [Sales setValue:value1 forKey:@"value1"];
            [Sales setValue:value2 forKey:@"value2"];
            [Sales setValue:value3 forKey:@"value3"];
            [Sales setValue:value4 forKey:@"value4"];
            [Sales setValue:value5 forKey:@"value5"];
            [context save:nil];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking `setValue:forKey:` on the array `Sales`.  That automatically invokes that method on every member of the array.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/setValue:forKey:):

> Invokes setValue:forKey: on each of the array's items using the specified value and key.

But you have then wrapped it in a for loop that repeats it ~1800 times.  Either remove the for loop, or invoke `setValue:forKey:` directly on each member of the array, eg.

```
        [Sales[i] setValue:value1 forKey:@"value1"];
```

If you do the latter, move the save outside the for loop, so the context is saved once at the end rather than after each and every item.

So either:

```
    [Sales setValue:value1 forKey:@"value1"];
    [Sales setValue:value2 forKey:@"value2"];
    [Sales setValue:value3 forKey:@"value3"];
    [Sales setValue:value4 forKey:@"value4"];
    [Sales setValue:value5 forKey:@"value5"];
    [context save:nil];
```

or

```
    for (int i = 0; i<Sales.count; i++)
    {
        [Sales[i] setValue:value1 forKey:@"value1"];
        [Sales[i] setValue:value2 forKey:@"value2"];
        [Sales[i] setValue:value3 forKey:@"value3"];
        [Sales[i] setValue:value4 forKey:@"value4"];
        [Sales[i] setValue:value5 forKey:@"value5"];
    }
    [context save:nil];
```

Comment: Sales is of type NSManagedObjectContext. It is not an array.

Comment: You declare it as NSArray, and assign it to a method that returns NSArray: `NSArray *Sales=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];`

Comment: well its weird cause it says Sales does not have a method objectAtIndex (or [i])

Comment: That is odd.  What happens if you change the name to something else, say `salesResults`?